# Swift: '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Any'

Tags: swift, string, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to check if the string is empty of not, if it is not empty, i want to display the at the textField (outUrl.text)

```
 let storage = UserDefaults.standard
 var mainsite = storage.object(forKey:"sitestring")  ?? ""

        if (mainsite != "") {
            outUrl.text = mainsite
        }
```

But I have error:
Error: != cannot be applied to operands of type string and any

How do i check if the string is not empty?

Comment: I edited the question title and tags, because actually Xcode has nothing to do with this (it's a feature of the Swift language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result returned by the Objective-C API `-[UserDefaults obejectForKey:]` is of type `id`, in order to accomodate various types of objects (`NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc, etc.). When accessed form Swift code, this becomes `Any?` (any type, perhaps `nil`).

If you know the stored value is indeed a string, you need to attempt cast it before comparing: `!=` between values of types `String` and `Any?` isn't defined by default! What meaning would that have?):

```
var mainsite = storage.object(forKey:"sitestring") as? String ?? ""
```

This way, you either get a `String` value (if the cast succeeds) or the empty string (if it fails, because either there is no object for key "sitestring" or it isn't convertible to a `String` value).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is to use the appropriate API (`string(forKey:`) which returns `String` rather than `Any` and optional bindings.

The benefit is you get rid of any type cast and the nil coalescing operator

```
if let mainsite = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"sitestring"), !mainsite.isEmpty {
    outUrl.text = mainsite
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result from UserDefaults.standard is of type Any?, so before assigning the value to mainsite variable, typecast it to String. Here is an example,

```
   let storage = UserDefaults.standard
   var mainsite = storage.object(forKey:"sitestring") as? String
```

Comment: There is no significant difference to Nicolas' answer.